# Подскажите библиотеки с++, нужна бибилотека, реализующая алгоритм хэширования SHA-1 и библиотека, позволяющая кодирвоать сообщение в base 64

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеки с++,  нужна бибилотека, реализующая алгоритм хэширования SHA-1 и библиотека, позволяющая кодирвоать сообщение в base 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openssl содержит реализацию практически всех алгоритмов, используемых в криптографии.

https://tls.mbed.org/source-code